# Variable x not working right

Tags: javascript, variables

Please help me out guys i have tried to figure this out for ages now. The problem i seem to have is second web page pops up right as the first one does even though it should pop up only after variable x is declared, here is my code try it out and you will see.

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var r=confirm("By pressing ok you are confirming your username and password");
if (r==true)
  {
  x="Thank You for Registering!";
  }
else
  {
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}

var nextpage;
if (x = "Thank You for Registering!"){
 window.open('Password.html');
}//end if
</script>
```

see the problem is that "password.html" is opened right as this page is opened when is should only open after x="thank you for Registering"
Please guys i will be forever grateful if someone figures this one out.

Answer (score 0):

'=' is an `assignment` operator whereas '==' is a `comparison` operator.
for example.if you write something like this.

```
if(x=1)//always true
{
}
else //this part will never be executed
{
}
```

then the above code will always result in true so else part will never be executed,you also are facing the same problem.so
Replace '=' with '=='

```
if (x == "Thank You for Registering!"){
 window.open('Password.html');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `x = "Thank You for Registering!"` you are assigning that string to `x`. After you do the assignment, it tests if the value is "true-ish," which it is. Instead of `=` (assignment), you want `==` (comparison).

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing the variable value correctly. You are doing `X= ""` which calls assignment not comparison. So for compare a value you need to put this in this way

```
x == "Thank You for Registering!"
```

`==` will do the job. Keep these things in practise.

Learn more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp).